# sans math version of Latin Modern

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif, latin-modern

I am trying to get a sans math version of the lmodern family using `\DeclareMathVersion` but my approach does not work and I do not see why. But I have to admit that I am not sure whether I use the correct fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareMathVersion{sansmath}
% Math letters from Latin Modern Sans
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sansmath}{OML}{lmsso}{m}{it}
% Math operators
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sansmath}{OT1}{lmss}{m}{n}
% Math symbols
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{sansmath}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
% Large symbols
%\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sansmath}{OMX}{lmssex}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{normal}  
$a b c \alpha \beta$

\mathversion{sansmath}  
$a b c \alpha \beta$
\end{document}
```

In both cases the result is the normal serif math font.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no Latin Modern Sans in OML encoding and LaTeX tells you:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/lmsso/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OML/cmm/m/it' instead on input line 18.
```

You can try Computer Modern Bright instead:

```
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sansmath}{OML}{cmbr}{m}{it}
```

Comment: So basically there are no math symbol in Latin Modern Sans?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech That's true.

Comment: I think this answer might be updated by mentioning `sansmathfonts` now.